# How to send data to a /dev/ttyAT port and see answer?

Tags: bash

I want to send some command to /dev/ttyAT port and at same time to read response.

This is what is working for now.

```
echo "AT+WIOCFG=21,4,1,0,0,0,0" > /dev/ttyAT; sleep 1;
echo "AT+WIOW=21,0" > /dev/ttyAT; sleep 1;
echo "AT+WIOCFG=22,4,1,0,0,0,0" > /dev/ttyAT; sleep 1;
```

But I need to remove sleep and execute next command when I get response from previous one.

I've tried with this,

```
echo ""AT+WIOW=21,0" > /dev/ttyAT | cat < /dev/ttyAT > result.txt & sleep 1; kill $!
```

but in order to kill `cat` process, I need to add `sleep 1;`, which is the same as before.

How to write some bash function to execute one command as soon as I get a response from the previous one?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  `read < /dev/ttyAT` might work, but I am not set up to test it.  Also, the `expect` program is designed for tx/rx exchanges, so might help you.